# Django: Why Filtering By Year Works, But Not Month and Day?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a simple datetime field named date.  Stores dates and time like this: 2015-07-04 01:40:00+00:00.

When I run

```
today = datetime.datetime.now().today()
x = game.objects.filter(date__year=today.year)
```

It works, however if i run

```
today = datetime.datetime.now().today()
x = game.objects.filter(date__month=today.month)
```

I get an empty list.

Comment: don't you thing its based on `game.objects.filter`?

Comment: Just want to confirm: `date` is a `DateTimeField`, yes?

Comment: Yes it is.  date = models.DateTimeField()

Answer (score 0):

Current month is July. If you filter by the year part of the date being equal to current month, then you search for records being in the year of 07 AD. I believe you do not have such records. You need to filter by month of the date if you want to filter by month.

Comment: That was a typo, updated it and now i get another error.

Comment: Are you sure that you have deleted any pyc files and restarted the server since you fixed the typo.